# Collecting and merging Service Analysis Line features using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, iteration

I try to collect and merge Service Analysis Line features after iteration. I name my analysis layers with the iteration values, but it doesn't help. The output feature datasets of the analysis named with consequent numbering (ServiceArea1, ServiceArea2, etc.) and the line feature classes like (SALines1, SALines2, etc.). The line features represents the right output (I tested). When I try to collect data, all the Collected Values call "Lines". I tried to write out the lines to feature class for every run by selecting the child data and feature class to feature class tool, but it didn't work. The result was not the output of the analysis result (SALines1, SALines2) but the same line features for every analysis result.
It seems that I miss a step that refers to the saved line feature classes in the created feature datasets. With this model I'm going to generate hundreds of Service Area layers and need to collect and merge the line outputs either as table or feature class and afterwards generate different statistics. Adding the results manually is out of the question.

Can anybody help with this?

[[image: model[1]]

Comment: I'd try 2 things: 1) Put Merge at the end of collect values. You talk about merging, but I don't see it in your model. Nor do you seem to have an output parameter set.  2) If that doesn't work, put Copy Features after Select Data and before Collect Values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it won’t solve this problem. You can’t see merge, because this is a submodel of the whole and just one version of all alternatives I tried. Merge doesn’t function with identically named input. Anyway the collected values seem to be not correct. I tried not just «feature class to feature class» but also «copy features» with the same wrong result, i.e the output feature classes were identical and not like the saved SALines1, SALines2. If it is not necessary I would avoid saving iteration results because it slows down the model. Any other ideas?

Comment: I mean that there is a problem with the selecting child data part. The selected child data «Lines» there does not point to the right output feature class in the generated feature dataset. However I tried to collect or save the output at the end of each iteration, I got wrong result.

Comment: If the select data collects values from temporary data, can be the reason that the selection «Lines» points to the first generated temp. value and all the later iterations got numbered temp output, and the select data still gets the first iteration result for every run? If this is the case how can I get around it?

Comment: Woow problem solved!!! There is an issue with "Select Data", but at last i found a workaround :) I've integrated another submodel that selects and collects the saved line elements (with iterating feature classes) and then in the main model I merged and created statistic from those. And it FUNCTIONS :) Thanks for all who have looked this and tried to find a solution!

Comment: Perhaps add the solution you found as an answer. It'll be helpful if anyone else has the same issue in the future and finds this question.

Answer (score 1):

Then here it comes the solution as an answer  There is an issue with "Select Data", but at last i found a workaround :) I've integrated another submodel that selects and collects the saved line elements (with iterating feature classes) and then in the main model I merged and created statistic from those. And it FUNCTIONS :) Thanks for all who have looked this and tried to find a solution!